# How to send data containing files from an html form via jQuery AJAX to Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, file

I can’t do a simple thing: send data containing files from an html form via jQuery AJAX to Laravel. I've tried literally everything and my Google doesn't show any more links that aren't highlighted in purple. In all examples it works, but for me it doesn't. I do not know why.

I can send plain text data like this:

View:

```
 <form name="property-form" id="property-form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id"
       value="{{isset($data['id']) ? $data['id']: '' }}">
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="{{isset($data['title']) ? $data['title']: '' }}">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<input type="button" id="save-property-button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
```

JS:

```
$('#save-property-button').click(function () {
    let form = $(this).closest('form')
    let formData = form.serialize();

    let token = $('#token').val();
    let type = 'PUT'
    let id = $('#id').val();
    let url = '/api/info/'+ id

    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseJSON);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, int $id)//InfoSetRequest
{
    return response()->json([
        '$request->all' => $request->all(),
        '$request' => $request,
        '$title' => $request->title,
        '$title2' => $request->input('title'),
        '$id' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

But as soon as I try to add files in any way, it stops working. I tried all the ways to form a formData and nothing worked.